# Como recorrer y extraer datos de una respuesta de un servicio SOAP, XML, en una función de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, function

es que no encuentro una buena forma de hacer lo siguiente, recorrer una respuesta `XML` de un servicio `SOAP` por ejemplo:

Tengo la siguiente respuesta del servicio:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://xxxxx.xxxxx.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.xxxx.com/xxxxx/xxx.xxx.xx.DeviceManagement/DeviceManagement.Core/PreActiveSimxxxxx/WSPreActivexxxxxg" 
xmlns:v1="http://www.x.cxxxom.co/xxxx/cxxx/WSRequestHeader2/v1.0" xmlns:pre="http://www.xxx.com.co/xxxx/CustomerManagement/PreActivexxxxxx">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsp:WSxxxxx>
         <v1:WSRequestHeader2>
            <v1:System>
               <v1:name>nnnn</v1:name>
               <v1:correlationID>000nnnnn</v1:correlationID>
               <v1:processingServer>nnnn</v1:processingServer>
            </v1:System>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         </v1:WSRequestHeader2>
         <pre:xxxxx>
            <pre:Origen>nnnnn</pre:Origen>
            <pre:Nombres>MARIA PEPITA</pre:Nombres>
            <pre:Apellidos>CHANGOS</pre:Apellidos>
            <pre:TipoDocumento>CXX</pre:TipoDocumento>
            <pre:NoDocumento>000000</pre:NoDocumento>
            <pre:FechaExpDocumento>00/00/0000</pre:FechaExpDocumento>
            <pre:Telefono>1111111111</pre:Telefono>
            <pre:Plan>PLAN MOVILXXXX</pre:Plan>
            <pre:CentralRiesgo>CVVVN</pre:CentralRiesgo>
            <pre:CentralRiesgoValidacion>TRUE</pre:CentralRiesgoValidacion>
            <pre:CentralRiesgoFecha>00/001/0000</pre:CentralRiesgoFecha>
         </pre:PXXXX>
      </wsp:XXXXXX>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Yo estaba pensando por ejemplo usando expresiones regulares y podría utilizar algo cómo

```
\(<pre:Nombres>)\i
```

ir buscando por etiqueta, pero el problema lo tengo cuando necesito devolver el valor de la etiqueta cuando la encuentre :/. Agradezco cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ocupar [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), esto convierte el XML en una especie de documento y lo puedes consultar con getElementById, querySelector, querySelectorAll, etc

```js
const XML =`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://xxxxx.xxxxx.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.xxxx.com/xxxxx/xxx.xxx.xx.DeviceManagement/DeviceManagement.Core/PreActiveSimxxxxx/WSPreActivexxxxxg" 
xmlns:v1="http://www.x.cxxxom.co/xxxx/cxxx/WSRequestHeader2/v1.0" xmlns:pre="http://www.xxx.com.co/xxxx/CustomerManagement/PreActivexxxxxx">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsp:WSxxxxx>
         <v1:WSRequestHeader2>
            <v1:System>
               <v1:name>nnnn</v1:name>
               <v1:correlationID>000nnnnn</v1:correlationID>
               <v1:processingServer>nnnn</v1:processingServer>
            </v1:System>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         </v1:WSRequestHeader2>
         <pre:xxxxx>
            <pre:Origen>nnnnn</pre:Origen>
            <pre:Nombres>MARIA PEPITA</pre:Nombres>
            <pre:Apellidos>CHANGOS</pre:Apellidos>
            <pre:TipoDocumento>CXX</pre:TipoDocumento>
            <pre:NoDocumento>000000</pre:NoDocumento>
            <pre:FechaExpDocumento>00/00/0000</pre:FechaExpDocumento>
            <pre:Telefono>1111111111</pre:Telefono>
            <pre:Plan>PLAN MOVILXXXX</pre:Plan>
            <pre:CentralRiesgo>CVVVN</pre:CentralRiesgo>
            <pre:CentralRiesgoValidacion>TRUE</pre:CentralRiesgoValidacion>
            <pre:CentralRiesgoFecha>00/001/0000</pre:CentralRiesgoFecha>
         </pre:PXXXX>
      </wsp:XXXXXX>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`;

let parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(XML, "text/xml");

console.log(xmlDoc.querySelector("Origen").innerHTML);
console.log(xmlDoc.querySelector("Nombres").innerHTML);
console.log(xmlDoc.querySelector("Apellidos").innerHTML);
console.log(xmlDoc.querySelector("TipoDocumento").innerHTML);
console.log(xmlDoc.querySelector("CentralRiesgoFecha").innerHTML);
```